# how can i determine successive (logic'1') bits in a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

i am pretty a new vhdl user and i am trying to solve a problem,which is difficult for me nowadays .  I have two std_logic_vectors.First one  has 5 bits,which must have (11111).Second one has 2040 bits,which is arbitral and i must divide up 2040 bits to 24 outputs that means each output must have 85 bits .First  i must determine by using a small vector(5bits)   the place of  successive 5 bits(11111) in a std_logic_vector,which has 2040 bits.After determing if there are  (11111) in a 2040bits vector ,the output should be  '1'  which is responsible 85 bits where there is (11111) .

to summarize

for example  i have 24 outputs   each control 85 bits of std_logic-vector(2040bits) 
if there is a 11111 in first 85 bits then output1 should be '1'
if there is a 11111 in 86 to 170 bits then output2 should be '1'
if there is a 11111 in 172 to 255 bits then output3 should be '1'  so on...

(11111) is the minimum value .it can be bigger to make an output logic '1'    Does someone have any idea about it??...  and ((if 2040bits are massive then i can reduce the number of bits))

Thanks

Comment: do you want tho have that synthesized? what speed are you targetting for?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean to search for the first vector in the second, however if you know that they will all be '1's, then the and_reduce macro works nicely.  Otherwise replace that with a comparison.

The general principal is to break it into two loops, the outside is for each output result, and the inside is for each possible 5 bit group.  The process can be done in serial or in parallel like below.

the way you've described the problem if 81 to 86 = "11111" there will be no pattern match.  if that should return a 1, then the array bounds will need to be altered slightly.

```
type slvArray is array (natural range <>) of standard_logic_vector;
subtype outputRange is natural range 0 to 23;
subtype partitionRange is natural range 0 to 84;

proc:process(clock)
    variable andResult : slvArray(outputRange)(partitionRange);
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        for olc in outputRange loop
            for ilc in partitonRange'low to partitionRange'high-4 loop
               andResult(olc)(ilc) <= and_reduce(slv2(olc*partitionRange'length + ilc to olc*partitionRange'length+ ilc + 4);
            end loop;
            output(olc) <= or_reduce(andResult);
        end loop;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you very much  voider  i consider it